# Why is this rspec test throwing a "undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass" error?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to integrate rspec_api_documentation (https://github.com/zipmark/rspec_api_documentation) into my sinatra app. I'm running into the error below. I've obviously simplified the error down to a bare test, because I think once I figure out what is wrong in the configuration, it'll work once reintegrated into my larger app.

Thanks!

**In app.rb:**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/index' do
  "hewoah!"
end
```

**In spec.rb:**

```
require "rspec_api_documentation"
require "rspec_api_documentation/dsl"

RspecApiDocumentation.configure do |config|
#  config.app = App
end

resource "Users" do
  get "/index" do
    example "Returns text" do
      do_request
      status.should be_ok
    end
  end
end
```

**Results of `rspec spec/acceptance/spec.rb --require ./app.rb`**
    F

```
Failures:

  1) Users GET /index Returns text
     Failure/Error: do_request
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/acceptance/spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.02234 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/acceptance/spec.rb:10 # Users GET /index Returns text
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get your bare application registered you'll need to set the app to the Sinatra::Application:

```
specApiDocumentation.configure do |config|
#  config.app = App 
end
```

To:

```
specApiDocumentation.configure do |config|
   config.app = Sinatra::Application
end
```